# Android Studio AVD error in elementary OS 0.4

Tags: drivers, android-studio

this is my system info picture:
[image]
when I open Android Studio, want to start Android virtual Device to run my android codes ,errors happen as below:

```
/home/bjming/Android/Sdk/tools/emulator -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Nexus_5X_API_23

sh: 1: glxinfo: not found

sh: 1: glxinfo: not found

libGL error: unable to load driver: r600_dri.so

libGL error: driver pointer missing

libGL error: failed to load driver: r600

libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so

libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast

X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)

  Major opcode of failed request:  155 (GLX)

  Minor opcode of failed request:  24 (X_GLXCreateNewContext)

  Value in failed request:  0x0

  Serial number of failed request:  33

  Current serial number in output stream:  34

QObject::~QObject: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread
```

how to resolve this problem???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the fix. You need to force Android Studio to use the system version of libstdc++

```
cd ~/Android/Sdk/tools/lib64/libstdc++
mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.bak
ln -s /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 ~/Android/Sdk/tools/lib64/libstdc++
```

Comment: thanks your answer. beacause of my linux local libstdc++, Android Studio's libstc++ not work well.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this command just change the things you need to, like the Nexus device to the one you are using.

```
LD_PRELOAD='/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21' ~/Android/Sdk/tools/emulator -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Nexus_4_API_23
```

This helped me, hope it helps you too